# How to reduce intrinsic python pillow noise?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pixel

In the following code I create a white image in Pillow, and change one pixel value to black. However, when I run the code about 20% of the other pixels also get darker. How might I reduce this noise, or eliminate it?

When creating this code I created the image separately then accessed in another python script. But, moving both segments to the same script, results in the same noise problem.
I tried running the pixel changing code in a while loop 1000+ times but that didn't change anything. It seams to only happen when the operator runs the code, it does slightly get worse with each operator run.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.new('RGB',(10,10), 'rgb(255,255,255)')
img.save("blank2.jpg")


img.putpixel((7,5),(0,0,0))
img.save("blank3.jpg")
```

Comment: Save it in another format with a compression algorithm better suited for your needs (`blank3.png` should resolve your issue)